# Does "rent out" only refer to when the owner offers something for others to pay to use, or also to when the user pays the owner to use something?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, language-change

I'm a gen-X native Australian English speaker and am listening to a YouTube video by a millennial native Australian English speaker in which he uses "to rent out" to refer to the person paying for the use of a service or infrastructure.

As a language nerd it sounded wrong to me, but I'm not certain, and checking various online dictionaries hasn't resolved it though some other online forums seemed to have some support both for my feeling, and that both are right. The third possibility is that this is a recent change in English usage in the last 20 to 30 years.

My instinct is that the owner offers it "out" so "out" fits for the owner providing it. But when I thinking about it "out" seems to have some similar usages to "up" in phrasal verbs indicating completeness or totality, in which "rent out" might be similar to "eat up" indicating the person is paying for use of the entire thing, not sharing with other renters.

Since I trust the contributors to this site more than other English forums I'm interested in your expert opinions and insights. Which use/uses is/are correct? Has it always been this way or is it undergoing change?

Here's the exact quote [from the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_rfIboPyYs&t=108s&ab_channel=ColdFusion):

> Worldcom didn't build landline cables or cellphone towers, but instead would **rent out** this infrastructure **from** other companies.

(Emphasis added by me.)

Comment: What's the exact quote?

Comment: It sounds as if the two options in your question are equivalent. The owner offers others to pay to use and taking him up on the offer another pays him to use it as stated. The question needs an example or other context. We are happy to help.

Comment: @Laurel: Exact quote and link to original added.

Comment: @Elliot: I really had trouble writing clear definitions of the two meanings!

Comment: Is the intent that Worldcom pays a (wholesale) fee to the owner and then charges a (retail) fee to Worldcom’s own clients? That would link the “rent out” part to Worldcom and their clients, and the “from” part to Worldcom and its supplier.

Comment: @Lawrence: I don't know anything not in the video, but I don't quite understand your comment. I can't see how "rent out" would be serving double duty if that's what you're saying?

Comment: What I meant was that a more natural reading would be something along the lines of “rent out *to customers* from *suppliers*”.

Comment: @Lawrence: Ah I see, I think. Did you listen to the audio though, because the intonation didn't make me think of that interpretation. Also it's not novel to him, it's just where I noticed it. Googling showed other people asking similar questions even if I wasn't satisfied with any answers I read.

Comment: No, sorry, I’m just going by the text you posted. I think it’s ambiguous. “Rent out” usually carries the notion that the subject of the clause is the lessor (‘owner’), but it is also used as an intensifier of sorts when the thing being rented is the whole of what is on offer: “We rented out the whole hall for our event.” This parallels usage such as “We blocked out the whole week for the event.”

Comment: @Lawrence: Yep that's pretty much my question. Apologies if my wording is sub-par (-:

Comment: People do sometimes use "took out" to refer to renting things though. For instance "We went to the bike hire shop and took out a tandem for the week"

Comment: @Lawrence I know the OP is Australian, though I'm not sure where you are speaking from. However in Britain I would not expect to see "rent out" as used in the example you have given. And it surprises me that it would be used like that in any mainstream English-speaking country. "Blocked out" or "Took out" - yes. But "They rented out the hall" is telling me that "they" are the people collecting the rent - not the ones paying it.

Comment: @BoldBen: At first I thought you made a typo for "book out", which is maybe an even closer analogy. If a hotel is "booked out" there are no rooms left but if I were to say "we booked out the hall" you would expect I was the one who made the booking and not the one in charge of the hall. Oh it seems I subconsciously came up with a similar example to WS2 above but with the inverse outcome for "book out" vs "rent out". Interesting.

Comment: @WS2 I’m speaking from an Australian context.

Comment: I don’t have any evidence to hand, but I feel that the Aussie dialect tends to admit more small words than BrE and that, as the OP suggests, it’s more pronounced with the younger (millennial) Aussies.

Comment: I don't know that anyone would use "took out" for a fixed asset like a room. It would usually be used for hiring mobile assets like bikes or tools.

Comment: @Lawrence I've lived in Australia, albeit long before there were such people as millennials, and I'm surprised. So if someone said "we've rented out the house" it could mean they were living in it?  Must be confusing for estate agents.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not correct usage; a verification in an online up to date¹ dictionary  shows that "out" is used only in the case when "rent" means "receiving" money in return for allowing someone to use your property, and at that it is an optional particle.

¹ <sub>*The dictionary used, from which is taken the following reference, results from a new release in March 21*</sub>

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/rent_2))
> **1** [transitive, intransitive] to regularly pay money to somebody so that you can use something that they own, such as a house, a room, some land, etc.
> ♦Are you looking to buy or rent?
> **rent something** to rent a house/an apartment
> to live in rented accommodation/housing/property
> ♦ The property is available to rent on a short-term lease.
> ♦ We're looking for a house to rent in the area.
> **rent something from somebody**
> ♦ Who do you rent the land from?
>
> **2** [transitive] to allow somebody to use something that you own such as a house or some land in exchange for regular payments
> **rent something (out)**
> ♦ We rented our house out for a year when we went abroad.
> ♦ She bought a three-bedroom flat with the objective of renting two rooms.
> ♦ He is making a profit from renting out the property.
> **rent something (out) to somebody**
> ♦ He rents rooms in his house to students.
> ♦ The land is rented out to other farmers.
> ♦ She agreed to rent the room to me.

I rather believe that you can trust your instinct and that the somewhat confusing word context is more likely to be at the root of an error in that speaker's English. An additional fact that tends to confirm this use of "out" is what can be read at the entry for this adverb in *The SOED*.

> (SOED) **2** Expr. motion or direction away from oneself, a center, a familiar place, the shore, etc., esp. to a remote point, to sea, to war, etc. Now also *spec.* (of a boat, train, post, etc.) going out, departing. [since] Old English  **b** From one's control or possession into that of others [since] Late Middle English.

in the same entry is still found the following.

> **6** To an end, completely, thoroughly, fully, to the utmost degree. Middle English.

Nevertheless, "**2b**" seems to prevail and coincide nicely with the sense in n° 2 of OALD.

*Remark*: It is to be noted that this verb is not considered to be a phrasal verb, at least not in OALD.